# How to get specific query value from string?

Tags: java, string, java-8

I would like to get `myInfo` value from the below-given string `test`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "{q=code=in=(100,110,120,100);product=in=(393,393);ID==33323323, myInfo==test, offset=0, limit=200}";
    }
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
test
```

***How to split and get the required value?***

Comment: `System.out.println(tes1.replaceAll("\\S+,\\s*myInfo==(\\S+),.+", "$1"));`

Comment: Thanks! Will this take care if the myInfo is not passed in query param?

Comment: @learngraphgrap, no. Also, if the parameter is not passed, it won't have a value, right?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Unfortunately,  not if `myInfo` isn't presented in query param, it will print full query param. `System.out.println("{ID==33323323, offset=0, limit=200}".replaceAll("\\S+,\\s*myInfo==(\\S+),.+", "$1"));` Output to console will  be: `{ID==33323323, offset=0, limit=200}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions for this task will be using [Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Here is code demo:

```
public class RegexDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "{q=code=in=(100,110,120,100);product=in=(393,393);ID==33323323, myInfo==test, offset=0, limit=200}";

        printMyInfoValue(test);
    }

    private static void printMyInfoValue(String test) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+myInfo==(\\w+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.printf("My Info value: %s\n", matcher.group(1).trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> test

At regex, we are checking if `myInfo` is presented in a text. If yes just group the results with parenthesis `()`.
For group with index 0 `group(0)` we will have full regex value:

> myInfo==test

For 1 group `group(1)` only value:

> test

It is exactly what we are looking for.
If no `myInfo` key is presented for input `text` -> no printing result.